# Can we have separate manifest for tablet and smartphones in Android?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to have a single apk with two separate Android manifest for smartphones and tablets?

If two separate manifests are not possible, could differentiate behaviour of the manifest for tablets and smartphones?

NOTE - This is regarding application permissions, intent filters etc mentioned in the android manifest.
Things that are to be configured during app installation.

Comment: Short answer: No. _Longish_ answer: Every project can contain just  the one Manifest file. If you need to create two different Manifest files for Tablets and Phones, you most probably would be better off creating two separate APK's. Alternatively, keep a single Manifest and check (through code) if the device is a Tablet or a Phone and show the appropriate Activities, Fragments, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for a alternative solution, say configure the project using gradle or maven.

Comment: I know it is one manifest per apk. I was looking for an alternative solution, say configure the manifest to behave separately for tablets and smartphones. or configure the gradle build to have one apk behave differently for phones and tablets.

Comment: There are lots of mechanisms that allow you to have different behaviour on phones and tablets (layout, resources, dimensions, ...). Can you explain what the differences in your case would be.

Comment: Example, I do not want the vibrate permission for tablets, or the app to listen to certain URL intent schemes in smartphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a single apk with two separate Android manifest for smartphones and tablets?

No. There's only a single manifest per APK. The manifest is static and cannot be varied at runtime.

> If two separate manifests are not possible, could differentiate behaviour of the manifest for tablets and smartphones?

You can build more than one APK from the same codebase with the differentiation applied to them.

Have a look at [product flavors](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html). You can have the main manifest with the common content for all flavors and then have flavor-specific manifests that contain the phone or tablet-specific additions. The build tooling merges the manifests together to get a single APK-specific manifest.

For distribution, have a look at [multiple APK support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using product flavours with gradle for same code base with different UI. But I want to have the single apk per app, for smartphones and tablets. Multi APK support is something I was not aware of. Seems like it might do the trick. :)

Comment: @B.B. :   Please accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: I would sure do so. :) The problem is I have the application is already in the playstore. The next release would be an update for the users. So I have to do a demo, and check if it works with the upgrade scenario for both phones and tablets. It's going to take some time.